# get object for logged in user, else create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

using rails 3:

in controller, i want to find an object for the logged in user, if it exists i want to use that else i want to create a new object for the user, how can i do this?

```
myObj = myObj.find(current_user.id)
```

How do i check that the object exists? is there a myObj.nil or myObj.exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if myObj
  myObj.find(current_user.id)
end
```

`myObj.find(current_user.id)` will only run if `myObj` exists.

EDIT: You can also do

```
if !myObj
  myObj = ...
end
myObj.find(current_user.id)
```

This will create `myObj` if it doesn't exist, and then run `myObj.find(current_user.id)`

**EDIT**
You should use this:
`myObj.find_or_create(current_user.id)`
assuming that myObj is an ActiveRecord (database model) object.

Comment: ok, but i want to check myObj.find(current_user.id) exists not myObj

Answer (score 0):

Ruby objects have a nil? method. You can check if it exist like this myObj.nil? or even just myObj

Comment: doesn't work, it throws an exception if you use the find method.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to add a has_many relationship to the User object so you can get them by:

current_user.myObjs

If the models are not directly connected but are through some other object then you can add:

has_many :myObjs, :through => :another_object

This would be the case if the user belonged to an account and the account had many myObjs objects, however not required if the myObjs belong_to User and User has_many myObjs.